# Clustering of data

Tags: matlab, cluster-analysis, euclidean-distance

I have a 2-dimensional dataset with several points (say 100), each having x and y coordinate in MATLAB. I need to cluster these points around some predefined points (say 5) according to the nearest neighbour (Euclidean distance). But, each predefined point has a limit to the number of points associated with it. for ex. predefined point 1 should have a cluster of 20 points from the dataset, the second should have 10, third should have 30 and so on without overlapping and each point should be classified. Is there any function that I can use to do this? In normal clustering, I cannot define the size of an individual cluster. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please specify your programming language, specify some code (your tries) etc. [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Sorry for the mistake. I am using MATLAB and I have used ISODATA as well as kmean method but i cannot specify the size of cluster.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `knnsearch`in MATLAB to find the nearest neighbours. https://ch.mathworks.com/help/stats/knnsearch.html

Therefore specify a reference point and select the amount of nearest points. The non-overlap needs to be addressed in a second step.